# R glm generating different p-values for same categorical variables of different type

Tags: r, for-loop, model, data.table, glm

I am generating a model fit using glm. My data has a mix of integer variables and categorical variables. Categorical variables are in the form of codes and hence integer type in the data. Initially when I tried to generate the model I passed the categorical variables in integer format as it is and got the model. I was looking at the p-values to check the once that are significant and noticed few variables were significant which I was not expecting.

This is when realized that may be the categorical variables in **integer** form are creating some issue. So like code 3 might get a higher importance than code 1 (**not sure on this and it would be great if someone can confirm this**). On doing some research I found that we can convert the categorical integer variable to **factor**. I did the same and re-generated the model.

I also saw some posts where it was mentioned to convert to **binary**, so I did that we well. So now I have 3 results -

1. r1 >> with categorical integer variables
2. r2 >> with categorical factor variables
3. r3 >> with categorical variable converted to binary

I feel that output 1 with categorical integer variables is incorrect (**Please confirm**). But between output 2 and 3 I am confused which one to consider as

1. p-values are different,
2. which one would be more accurate
3. can I related the p-values of output 3 with output 2?
4. How does glm handle such variables
5. Hope glm inside a for loop is not an issue
6. My database is big, can we do glm using data.table?

I am pasting below my code with some sample data to be reproduced

```
library("plyr")
library("foreign")
library("data.table")

#####Generating sample data

set.seed(1200)
id <- 1:100
bill <- sample(1:3,100,replace = T)
nos <- sample(1:40,100,replace = T)
stru <- sample(1:4,100,replace = T)
type <- sample(1:7,100,replace = T)
value <- sample(100:1000,100,replace = T)

df1 <- data.frame(id,bill,nos,stru,type,value)

var1 <- c("bill","nos","stru")

options(scipen = 999)
r1 <- data.frame()

for(type1 in unique(df1$type)){
  for(var in var1){
    # dynamically generate formula
    fmla <- as.formula(paste0("value ~ ", var))

    # fit glm model
    fit <- glm(fmla, data=df1[df1$type == type1,],family='quasipoisson')
    p.value <- coef(summary(fit))[8]

    cfit <- coef(summary(fit))
    # create data frame
    df2 <- data.frame(var = var, type = type1, basket="value",p.value = cfit[8],stringsAsFactors = F)
    r1 <- rbind(r1, df2)
  }
}

##### converting the categorical numeric variables to factor variables

df1$bill_f <- as.factor(bill)
df1$stru_f <- as.factor(stru)

var1 <- c("bill_f","nos","stru_f")

r2 <- data.frame()

for(type1 in unique(df1$type)){
  for(var in var1){
    # dynamically generate formula
    fmla <- as.formula(paste0("value ~ ", var))

    # fit glm model
    fit <- glm(fmla, data=df1[df1$type == type1,],family='quasipoisson')
    p.value <- coef(summary(fit))[8]

    cfit <- coef(summary(fit))
    # create data frame
    df2 <- data.frame(var = var, type = type1, basket="value",p.value = cfit[8],stringsAsFactors = F)
    r2 <- rbind(r2, df2)
  }
}

#####converting the categorical numeric variables to binary format (1/0)

df1$bill_1 <- ifelse(df1$bill == 1,1,0)
df1$bill_2 <- ifelse(df1$bill == 2,1,0)
df1$bill_3 <- ifelse(df1$bill == 3,1,0)

df1$stru_1 <- ifelse(df1$stru == 1,1,0)
df1$stru_2 <- ifelse(df1$stru == 2,1,0)
df1$stru_3 <- ifelse(df1$stru == 3,1,0)
df1$stru_4 <- ifelse(df1$stru == 4,1,0)

var1 <- c("bill_1","bill_2","bill_3","nos","stru_1","stru_2","stru_3")

r3 <- data.frame()

for(type1 in unique(df1$type)){
  for(var in var1){
    # dynamically generate formula
    fmla <- as.formula(paste0("value ~ ", var))

    # fit glm model
    fit <- glm(fmla, data=df1[df1$type == type1,],family='quasipoisson')
    p.value <- coef(summary(fit))[8]

    cfit <- coef(summary(fit))
    # create data frame
    df2 <- data.frame(var = var, type = type1, basket="value",p.value = cfit[8],stringsAsFactors = F)
    r3 <- rbind(r3, df2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you dynamically generate the formula?

Comment: @Koot6133, I want to change for different variables and hence the use of formula

Answer (score 0):

Your feeling is mostly correct. For a GLM you should make the distinction between continious variables and discrete (categorical) variables.

Binary variables are variables which contain only 2 levels, for example 0 and 1. 
Since you only have variables with 2+ levels, you should use the factor() function.

Comment: Do you mean to say converting the categorical variables to binary would give incorrect result? how does glm treat them?

Comment: You lose information when you convert a categorical variable to a binary variable. Check for example your "bill" variable. It contains of levels 1,2 and 3. After converting it changes levels 2/3 to one single level, namely 0.